# How to mock configuration class for test

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito, spring-test

I am facing with NPE.

I am writing test for my credential class but I am facing with NPE error. Here is my test class

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class CredentialServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private Properties properties;

    @Spy
    private Mapper mapper = Mockito.spy(new Mapper(properties));

    @Test
    void testGetCredentials() {
        when(properties.getHost()).thenReturn("http://localhost:8080");
        when(credentialRepository.findByCredentialSenderAndInactiveFalse(credential.getCredentialSender())).thenReturn(credential);
        CredentialsDTO actualCredentials = credentialService.getCredentials(headers);

        assertEquals(actualCredentials, credentialsDTO);
    }
```

Then I was able to mock `properties.getHost()` as you can see in the test class. However, I am facing with NPE because in my mapper I need to use `properties.getHost()` again. My mapper as below

```java
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Mapper {
    
    private Properties properties;

    public CredentialsDTO mapperCredentialToDTO(Credential credential) {
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();

        TypeMap<Credential, CredentialsDTO> propertyMapper = modelMapper.createTypeMap(Credential.class,
                CredentialsDTO.class);

        CredentialsRoleDTO credentialRoleDTO = mapperCredentialsToCredentialsRoleDTO(credential);
        List<CredentialsRoleDTO> credentialsRoleDTO = Arrays.asList(credentialRoleDTO);

        propertyMapper.addMappings(mapper -> mapper.map(src -> credentialsRoleDTO, CredentialsDTO::setRoles));
        propertyMapper.addMappings(mapper -> mapper.map(src -> credential.getCredentialSender(), CredentialsDTO::setToken));
        propertyMapper.addMappings(mapper -> mapper.map(src -> properties.getHost().concat(URLEnum.VERSIONS.getUrl()), CredentialsDTO::setUrl));

        return modelMapper.map(credential, CredentialsDTO.class);
    }
```

In the line `propertyMapper.addMappings(mapper -> mapper.map(src -> properties.getHost().concat(URLEnum.VERSIONS.getUrl()), CredentialsDTO::setUrl));` properties is always null.

**Note: I need to Spy my Mapper class. I can't mock it because of other tests**

Last but not least, here you can find my Properties class

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myapp")
@Component
@ConstructorBinding
@Data
public class Properties {

    private String host;

}
```

How can I handle that? (I believe that I am having problem with initialization)

The problem is still exist!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `@InjectMock` instate of `@Spy` annotation. Already you are spying your class with `Mockito.spy`. Below code should solve your problem

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class CredentialServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private Properties properties;

    @InjectMocks
    private Mapper mapper = Mockito.spy(new Mapper(properties));

    @Test
    void testGetCredentials() {
        when(properties.getHost()).thenReturn("http://localhost:8080");
        when(credentialRepository.findByCredentialSenderAndInactiveFalse(credential.getCredentialSender())).thenReturn(credential);
        CredentialsDTO actualCredentials = credentialService.getCredentials(headers);

        assertEquals(actualCredentials, credentialsDTO);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I handle that? (I believe that I am having problem with initialization)

You should make the properties variable as non-static field. This way Mockito can spy on it.

Updated code:

```
public class Mapper {

    private final Properties properties;

    public Mapper(Properties properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    public CredentialsDTO mapperCredentialToDTO(Credential credential) {
        ...
    }
}
```

After that, update the test code:

```
@Test
void testGetCredentials() {
    when(credentialRepository.findByCredentialSenderAndInactiveFalse(anyString())).thenReturn(credential);

    Properties properties = Mockito.mock(Properties.class);
    when(properties.getHost()).thenReturn("http://localhost:8080");

    Mapper mapper = new Mapper(properties);

    credentialService.getCredentials(headers, mapper);
}
```

---

SECOND OPTION - you can use a mocking framework like **Mockito Inline**.

Add dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Update the test:

```
@Test
void testGetCredentials() {
    when(credentialRepository.findByCredentialSenderAndInactiveFalse(anyString())).thenReturn(credential);

    MockedStatic<Properties> mockedProperties = Mockito.mockStatic(Properties.class);
    mockedProperties.when(() -> Properties.getHost()).thenReturn("http://localhost:8080");

    Mapper mapper = new Mapper();

    credentialService.getCredentials(headers, mapper);

    mockedProperties.close();
}
```

Comment: I have tried that but doesn't works. As I mentioned in the question I always have null inside `properties` variable

Comment: @Serdar I think the problem is that Mockito does not spy on static fields. The properties variable in your Mapper class is a static field, so Mockito is not able to spy on it.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I can't make changes to the source code. As I can see, you want me to make changes to the source code.

Comment: @Serdar If you cannot make changes to the source code, then the only way to mock the static properties field is to use a mocking framework like Mockito Inline. Mockito Inline allows you to spy on final classes and methods, including static fields. I can updated the answer

Comment: I have made changes but have not been able to import `MockitoInline`

Comment: @Serdar why you have not been able to import MockitoInline?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255569/discussion-between-serdar-and-zufar-sunagatov).

Comment: @ZufarSunagatov why are you talking about static fields? The OP has not used a static field anywhere.